# C insertion sort with function as parameter

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement an insertion sort algorithm and it almost works. My code is the following:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int compare_desc(const char *input1, const char *input2){
    char a = (*input1);
    char b = (*input2);
    
    if (a == b){
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (a > b){
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 1;
}



int compare_ignore_case_asc(const char *input1, const char *input2){
    char a = tolower(*input1);
    char b = tolower(*input2);

    if (a == b) {
        return 0;
    } 
        
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    }
        
    return -1;
}

void insertion_sort(char *array, size_t n, int (*compare)(const char *, const char *))
{
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
       for (size_t j = i; j > 0 && compare(&array[j-1], &array[j]); --j){
           char temp = array[j-1];
           array[j-1] = array[j];
           array[j] = temp;
       }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code compares with the two compare functions (they are already correct and tested with test cases).

Am I somehow misunderstanding the point of insertion sort?

The problem I'm facing is the following:

```
'insertion_sort':
=================
After executing the function 'insertion_sort' the order of the values in the array 'base' is not as expected!
String representation of the contents of the array 'base' after execution:
Expected: "First"
Actual  : "iFstr"
The following code snippet led to this error:
char array[] = "rtsFi";
size_t length = 5;
int (*compare)(const char *, const char *) = compare_ignore_case_asc;
insertion_sort(array, length, compare);
```

Where is my mistake?

I already tried and google and debug but I don't see the mistake I am currently making.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are using your compare function incorrectly: `&& compare(&array[j-1], &array[j]);` This only checks that return value is not 0. It does not care if it is `>0` or `<0`. As long as you don't have duplicate elements, this will always be true.

Comment: You don't need to do these distinctions in your compare functions. Unless you define it to be different from common sorting functions, you can just use `return a - b;` or `return b-a;` as the exact value does not matter.

Comment: the return value of your compare functions indicates should or shouldn't swap the two elements passed in as parameters. If it should be swaped, you return true, otherwise false. You don't need to know if they equals to each other. For insertion sort, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/ is very detailed description and includes a step by step demonstration. (They have bunch of other algrithm, too)